# Regular Expression to Replace xxx(zzz)xxx format in c#

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to replace xxx()xxx in this format xxx(zzz)xxx with nothing.

here is example:  Sara(56)Gorge => 56

Comment: What language/flavor of regex?

Comment: Actually nothing apear in my mind but i just know it must be something like str.Replace("/w/d(*)/w/d") but * not passed

Comment: Im using C# (mentioned in topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#:

```
var result = Regex.Replace("Sara(56)Gorge", @"[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)[^(]*", "$1");
```

Comment: I don't think `zzz` is necessarily numeric. Also, is there a reason why Gorge can't contain parens?

Comment: @Tim: About numeric: already fixed. About Gorge not containing parenthesis: I had to come up with some delimiter, because the OP didn't specify clear rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
@"\S+?\((\S+?)\)\S+"
```

As follows:

```
var pattern = @"\S+?\((\S+?)\)\S+"
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1");
```